# make text background colour fit text exactly, removing 'padding'

Tags: html, css

I need to be able to create a background of black around this text that isn't padded on the top or bottom. Currently, the padding is at 0, but I need to be able to clip it somehow? What I mean is this is the current text:

[image: padded text]

And I need it to be like this:

[image]

I don't mind how this is achieved, so long as it can still have a transparent background above and below.

Current css is:

```
padding:0em 0.2em 0em 0.2em;
display:inline-block;
background-color:#000;
color:#FFF;
```

Thanks!

Comment: How about negative padding? Could it work?

Comment: CSS doesn't support negative padding unless I'm wrong?

Comment: I don't know, I just assumed it could, since negative margin works fine. I can be wrong, of course.

Comment: This may sound silly, but have you considered using an image? Or does the text have to be dynamic?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove white space above and below large text in an inline-block element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061228/remove-white-space-above-and-below-large-text-in-an-inline-block-element)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add a `line-height` property that is something lower than 1.0em, for example:

```
line-height: 0.75em;
```

Note that this doesn't work on inline elements, so ensure that `display` is set to `block` or `inline-block`.

You may also need to fine-tune the vertical positioning using `padding-top` and/or `padding-bottom`, depending on the font that is used.

Comment: Chrome on a Mac. Positioning is off.

Comment: Works for me! Thank you, it was so simple, also worked out that if you use height and line height you can fine tune the position further

Comment: @BenM it works on Mac Chrome 28. I [updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YHgWV/3/) by reducing the line-height to 0.60em and there is no black line across the bottom. Obviously, the line-height needs to be fine-tuned according to whatever font is used and even further tweaked with padding-top and padding-bottom.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a line-height that is lower than the font-size:

```
padding:0em 0.2em 0em 0.2em;
display:inline-block;
background-color:#000;
color:#FFF;
font-size: 21px;
line-height: 15px;
```

Make sure display is block or inline-block.

MrSlayer just beat me to it!

Answer (score 1):

Here is [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/agugab/2/edit)

Make your CSS as below

```
padding:0.2em 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em;
display:inline-block;
background-color:#000;
color:#FFF;
font-size:25px;  
line-height:8px
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/J42cK/)**

```
<div>Some text</div>
```

### CSS

```
div
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    color:#fff;
}
div:before
{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    background: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 68%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;       
}
```