# How do I vertically fill a container with uppercase text using JS/CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a text that is uppercase, e.g. `ABC`.
As it is uppercase, all characters have the same height.
I also have a container (`div`) with fixed height, e.g. `100px`.

How do I make this text fill it vertically, so each letter is exactly 100 pixels high?

I tried `font-size: 100px`, but it does not fill the container (there are gaps above and below).
See http://jsfiddle.net/6z8un/1/ for an example.

**UPDATE 1:**
Let's assume all characters actually have the same height (difference either does not exist or is negligible). Otherwise the question does not make much sense.

**UPDATE 2:**
I am pretty sure it can be solved using https://stackoverflow.com/a/9847841/39068, but so far I had no perfect solution with it. I think ascent and descent are not enough, I would need something else for the top space.

Comment: That is because a Font usually has it's own whitespace. So you need to solve that with `line-height`

Comment: Uppercase letters do not generally have the same height. This should be obvious for characters like É, Å, and Ç. In many fonts, J and Q are taller than most other uppercase letters A–Z.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061228/remove-white-space-above-and-below-large-text-in-an-inline-block-element

Comment: I do not think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061228/remove-white-space-above-and-below-large-text-in-an-inline-block-element covers the possible answers well enough, it seem not to consider JS solution at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I made a small script that measures letter heights using canvas (would be a good thing to put on GitHub I suppose).
It is currently slightly unprecise, mostly because of caching.

I have published it as a library on GitHub, see here: https://github.com/ashmind/textmetrics.

Unfortunately I did not have time to make demo work as a GitHub page yet, so I can't link to it.

Answer (score 2):

`line-height` http://jsfiddle.net/6z8un/2/ will not solve the problem because this will not remove the whitespaces. You could apply the size by hardcoding (for me it fits with font-size of 126px) But this is different to every user (sans-serif can be configured by user/system/browser)

Windows default sans-serif font `MS sans serif` is different to `Droid sans serif` on Android or `DejaVu Sans` on Ubuntu.

To solve this problem, you could set a font to default, like `Times New Roman`, but not every system does have this font by default.

To solve this, you could use a custom font imported from a server like htttp://google.com/fonts
but not every browser does support custom fonts.

I think the only way to solve this is to use an image.

But custom fonts should do their job on modern browsers too :) (e.g.: http://jsfiddle.net/6z8un/5/ )

Comment: This is the only answer that actually comes close to a real solution that works reliably on all browsers / systems (images)

Comment: Yes, I know I can hardcode it for a given font, but I am interested in font-independent solution (I am looking into building a jQuery plugin that should work for any font).

Comment: You need to know the percentage of whitespace... the only way you could achieve this for every font, would be analiying the font files, and this will be a very slow code...

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. I hope this can help you.

```
<div class="outer"><div class="inner">ABC</span></div>

.outer {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 75px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.inner {
    font-size: 100px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin-top: -18px;    
}
```

Note: As I know whenever we use font-size the upper and lower gap is also the part of height. I mean font-size = upper gap + actual height of font + lower gap. So if we want 100px div then use font-size larger than 100.

Comment: The outer div is not `100px` high, and this depends on hardcoded height values, which may differ for browsers, fonts, and individual characters.

Comment: As I know whenever we use font-size the upper and lower gap is also the part of height. I mean font-size = upper gap + actual height of font + lower gap. So if we want 100px div then use font-size larger than 100.

Comment: Then add that to your answer, since the OP asked:
"How do I make this text fill it vertically, so each letter is *exactly 100 pixels* high?"

Answer (score 0):

Is this ok?

http://jsfiddle.net/6z8un/4/

HTML:

```
<div><span>ABC</span></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
span {
    font-size:136px;
    margin-top:-25px;
    display:inline-block;
};
```