# Remove space above and below the text inside the <a> tag

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Below you see a printscreen of a `<a>` tag with a light blue background.

As you can see, there are space above and below the text inside the `<a>` tag.

Is it possible to remove the space around the text?

Kind regards

[image]

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Yes, that's possible, but please post your code first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove white space above and below large text in an inline-block element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061228/remove-white-space-above-and-below-large-text-in-an-inline-block-element)

Comment: @Felix http://jsfiddle.net/lassebjensen/cFjt6/

Comment: @Siyah http://jsfiddle.net/lassebjensen/cFjt6/

Comment: In my jsfiddle example I am using default font so the top- and bottommargins are not 37px and 67px.

Answer (score 0):

You need the line-height to be smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could...

Option 1:

```
a {
    padding: 0; /* This will probably work A.F.A.I.K. */
    display: inline-block;
    /* If it doesn't, adding inline-block display will it inline **and** have
    a CSS box... but I'm not sure if this is recommended, honestly. */
}
```

Option 2:

```
a {
    line-height: 0;
    /* Mess with the line-height value to change the
    "Line Height" in an inline element */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically `<a>` tag does not have such padding. Tell me, if this tag is inside any `<li>` tag or anything else.