# Remove white space at the top and the bottom in h3

Tags: html, css, removing-whitespace

**h3 with white space at the top and the bottom**

[image]

I have some white space around my h3. To align it the same as some pictures I want to delete the white space at the top and the bottom of the h3. The margin is 0, but there is still space between the top and the bottom of the text. How do I solve this?

this is my code:

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h3>title</h3>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you with CSS, you will need to provide your existing CSS in addition to your HTML; we can't reproduce your problem without it. Please update your question so that it shows your CSS as well, thus forming a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confused about what the whitespace is. It's the full line height of the text, which accounts for potential above and below text characters, like accents and dangling letters. If you want to squish this whitespace (not recommended), set the line height to something smaller than the default, like

```
line-height: 0.8em;
```

Comment: I understand, when a title is HËLLÔ, then the h3 uses the full space. Thank you very much!

Comment: I did! But when I change the line-height, I can not yet margin on the highest letter.

Comment: @AndyRay How to help others find the answer its solution for particular user .. ?? dynamically you also know this happens with browser default css . am i right !!

Comment: No that's not @RïshïKêshKümar, but of all the comments this is the "best" solution.

Comment: @Martijn .. Check My Ans ... and set the `<style> * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}       h3 {
        margin-top: 0px;
    }     </style>`

Comment: +1. This seems to be the right answer. I don't know why people down-voted it. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/14061972/470749

Answer (score 0):

Remove the padding of the container element (in your example, the `<body>` tag):

```
body { padding: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Just Remove The Browser Default `Margin` and `Padding`** Apply Top Of Your Css.

```
<style>

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

</style>
```

> NOTE:

- Try to Reset all the `html elements` before writing your css.

**OR** [ `Use In Your Case` ]

```
<style>

  *{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

h3 {
        margin-top: 0px;
    }

</style>
```

---

**DEMO:**

```css
<style>

  *{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

h3 {
        margin-top: 0px;
    }

</style>
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h3>title</h3>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is still some space between the top from which it is aligned and from the top of the highest letter. You can see it when you select the text. Sorry, but this is not the solution.

Comment: It's Margin is zero , so how and where you see the space.. I can't believe .. okzz listen go and just google it for .. how to remove browser default css !! So you can easily understand what going on... And if you thik `line-height:0.8 is solution` then go for it..

Comment: Sorry .. but I don't thik it's right ans .. bcoz when you run the same code in different _different browser then you get the real difference .. between .. So best of luck.. happy to help.. I don't have any problem !! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As noted before, it is hard to reproduce your situation without the full CSS code that you have also.

However, a quick test of this gave me a `h3` without any whitespace:

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body style="padding: 0;">    
  <h3 style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">test</h3>
 </body>
</html>
```

It is probably browser dependent what the default margins/paddings on both the  `body` and `h3` elements are. I hope this helps you.