# Text appears in higher part of a div

Tags: html, css

I currently have the following html.

```
<div id="img_preview_text_container" style="position: absolute; top: 156px; left: 50px; font-family: Oklahoma; width: 376px; height: 75px; color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">
<div class="customOnePreviewText">ASDF</div>
</div>
```

The css for `.customOnePreviewText` is:

```
.customOnePreviewText {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

The challenge I'm having is that the text appears in the upper part of the div.  I'd like the type to be centered in the div meaning not a bottom part off or the entire div to just be the size of the text.  This is what I have now.

[image]

the black area is the div highlighted.

Comment: that space is preserved for [Descenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender) letters like `g,y`

Comment: Can that be removed?  I only use CAPS . @ZohirSalak

Comment: [Found it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061228/remove-white-space-above-and-below-large-text-in-an-inline-block-element), The thing is you'll have to adjust the line height to your font and if you ever change it you'll have to adjust it again which is just a pain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure there's no more html/css that might be affecting it? I copied the code you've provided and can't seem to reproduce the issue.

Have you tried using flexbox? Hard to say if this will solve your problem as I couldn't reproduce it but should make your life easier in any case.

```css
.customOnePreviewText {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 48px;
  background-color:white;
}

#img_preview_text_container {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Oklahoma; 
  width: 376px;
  height: 75px; 
  color:rgb(255, 0, 0); 
  background-color:black;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center
}
```

```html
<div id="img_preview_text_container">
  <div class="customOnePreviewText">ASDF</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's in a light box but I don't think that would affect it?  That's an element up @nathan.medz

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the translate within the inner div, you could adjust the margin from `0` to `0 25%` (0 top/bottom, 25 left/right) to center the writing. (see snippet - although you can't see the image in the snippet, you get the idea)

```css
.customOnePreviewText {
  margin: 0 25%;
  position:absolute;
  top: 50%;
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

```html
<div id="img_preview_text_container" style="position: absolute; top: 156px; left: 50px; font-family: Oklahoma; width: 376px; height: 75px; color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">
<div class="customOnePreviewText">ASDF</div>
</div>
```

An alternative to the above would be to use translateX(50%), but I think the above is a simpler solution. Your code seems to show confused usage of translateY (which moves the text down rather than across). 
Yet another solution would be to set a left position.

I would highly recommend switching to using relative position as you may find the task of positioning the text and image a lot simpler - just my tuppence.

Good luck!