# CSS fonts have different "padding"

Tags: css, fonts, padding, spacing

I want to make a Logo out of two Fonts, but as you can see here, [one font has close to no "padding" on top (left) and the other (right) font has](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9KNO.png). This makes it difficult to line them up. This is how i import the fonts:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'hatton';
    src: url(fonts/Hatton-Medium.otf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family:'neuemachina';
    src: url(fonts/NeueMachina-Regular.otf);
}
```

Is there anything i can add to the import, so the fonts have the same "padding"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what for do you use the fonts? this is not a good practice, but it will help: *{padding:0}

Comment: @hamid they are called Hatton Medium and NeueMachina. Adding padding: 0; doesnt change anything.

Comment: can you give us some html and css code what you've tried so far?

Comment: You can move the font a little higher with line-height.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove white space above and below large text in an inline-block element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061228/remove-white-space-above-and-below-large-text-in-an-inline-block-element)

Comment: Thanks @LarsFlieger, this answers my question. I found a unsatisfying solution of adjusting by pixels... very sad, but it seems that there is no easy solution for this.