# Is the space in the top element a padding?

Tags: html

An element's padding is the space between its content and its border.

Consider the code below:

```
<p style="background-color: tomato; border: 1px solid black; padding:0px; ">A paragraph</p>
```

Here I am expecting no space between the text and the border because I am setting the padding to 0px, But I got the opposite result as shown in picture.

[image]

I am sure that, that space is not a padding, so why I am getting that space?
Also is there any way to get rid of it?

Thanks)

Comment: That depends on the typeface

Comment: you can set the `line-height: 1` also typeface may create some extra space

Comment: Check out [The Accepted Answer To This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061228/remove-white-space-above-and-below-large-text-in-an-inline-block-element)

Comment: Thank you @Daniel A. white, I am not setting any font, so i guess the chrome browser uses its default text, which i guess Times New Roman.

Comment: You can check what it is by looking at the [devtools box model](https://www.codecademy.com/article/f1-devtools-box-model).

Comment: Thanks @Sifat Haque, line-height: 1; did not solve the problem, the top space is still there)

Comment: Thanks @zak, i am currently reading your link, it seems related to my problem

Comment: @Ninja you can try `line-height: 0.7`

Comment: Thanks @Sifat Haque)) the line-height: does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Desktop browsers (including Firefox) use a default line-height 1.2 , depending on the element's font-family.

if you apply line-height = 1, then your problem solved ✅.

```html
<p style="background-color: tomato; border: 1px solid black; padding:0px; line-height:1;">A paragraph</p>
```

Comment: Thanks @Savraj Dutta), but line-height does not solve the problem.