# Remove Spaces on Top and Bottom Of A String Div

Tags: html, css, frontend

As said in the title, how do we remove empty white spaces from top and bottom of a string div?

I used Chrome inspect tool to check the div but there aren't any margins or paddings. I also tried to play around with the height and line-height of the div but I think it is a little bit of a hack fix.

```css
.top {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
.bottom {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
.middle {
  font-size: 50px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="middle">HelloWorld</div>
<div class="bottom"> </div>
```

[image]

Comment: use this text `ẐÂpj` and you will understand the purpose of that space (don't try to remove it)

Comment: Nice! I didn't think about those characters. Is there anyway that we can make the height changes according to the text? e.g: with `ẐÂpj` set it to a larger height and `HelloWorld` to a smaller height.

Answer (score 0):

`line-height:` would do the trick however, you may encounter problems when you try to add certain text like Êj.

You may check this detailed [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061228/remove-white-space-above-and-below-large-text-in-an-inline-block-element).

Comment: Thanks! I played around with `line-height` for a little bit but i think it is a hack more than a solution because we need to play with its values.